# 403 permission denied for html type pictures

Tags: php, html, apache, request

PHP 7.0 / when page load , only pictures with type jpeg successfully load. Network tab under developer tool, Other picture requests are done with type html and they fail "Access denied" but other request with type jpeg went through.

Already check apache2.conf /webroot is set to granted.

Comment: What is type html?? Show your code for successful and faulty ones

Comment: I think he means the `mime` type is `text/html` which makes sense if he is getting the generic Apache 403 page.

Comment: yes prodigitalson. https://drive.google.com/file/d/18G5wAIkNv0gxXq2_O6Q6iBXvVi_RjPMb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you checked your file permissions? are they set to match the apache env vars?  
    **/etc/apache2/envvars**:export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data  AND   
    **/etc/apache2/envvars**:export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrato85 gave the answer. I had to change permission for the files(pics) even tho i had permission for the others

Answer (score 1):

See this:  [Deprecating web hosting support in Google Drive](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html)

Google deprecated serving static content from Google Drive back in 2015.  That means they are free to create any weirdness whenever they want, like 403 for some file types.  Best to move to a supported platform like [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), etc.